# PHP 7.1.x - mysqli_connect Isn't Defined (Extension is turned on)

Tags: php, mysqli, wampserver, php-7.1

## Background

I have WAMP Server (3.0.6) installed on my Windows 10 computer. I am developing a WordPress site using a few custom MySQL tables, so I'm using `$wpdb`.

## Problem

I was running on PHP 7.0.10, and everything was fine. This morning, I installed PHP 7.1.4, and suddenly I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in ...\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1573

I dug into it and traced the issue back to the `__construct()` function, and this `if` statement:

```
if ( function_exists( 'mysqli_connect' ) ) {
```

A var_dump showed me that `function_exists( 'mysqli_connect' )` is returning `false`.

[image]

## Not the answer

The problem is **NOT** that I don't have the `mysqli` extension enabled:

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Things That I've Tried

I have switched back to 7.0.x (and the error disappeared), deleted 7.1.4, reinstalled 7.1.4, and switched back to it. It still doesn't work.

I tried 7.1.0, and it doesn't work.

I've tried toggling the extension on and off, and that changes nothing.

I've tried copying the actual `php_mysqli.dll` file from the working 7.0.10 directory, into the 7.1.4 directory, and that doesn't work.

**Edit**

Per request, I've added screenshots of what is what is showing from `phpinfo()`. Under 7.0, I see the info section for mysqli, and under 7.1, the section is missing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: All your problem is a typo(

Comment: The error you got was from `mysql_connect()`, but I find it odd that you got a false result when checking if the `mysqli_connect()` function exists.

Comment: `wp-includes\wp-db.php` that being part of your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43848269/1, suggests you're using wordpress. Maybe you've some leftover code with `mysql_` somewhere. Btw; did you restart after making those changes?

Comment: Interesting you decided to remove the actual error message...

Comment: This question isn't very understandable without the error, so I've rolled back your edit. Typos happen - if you're embarrassed by it, delete the question.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say?

Comment: @Jon, The entire section for mySQLi is missing, despite it being enabled in the `php.ini` file. Will make screenshots.

Comment: @AndyMercer Can you confirm in the phpinfo that the php.ini being used is one of the ones you've edited?

Comment: After Googling "WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL" because it's in a screenshot you added, I found this Q&A https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160889/wp-use-ext-mysql - This answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/237413 states *"Setting the WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL constant to true causes WordPress to use the MySQL extension instead of the MySQLi extension"*. See the other answer in there also.

Comment: @Jon Stirling, it's using the `ini` file in the apache installation? But when I look there, that file is a symlink, and not openable. Except that when I open the ini file from the WAMP menu, it opens. Which is really strange. However, the extension IS enabled in the ini file that opens from the WAMP menu which is supposidly the one being used.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I've checked on WP_USE_EXT. That isn't the issue here, though I appreciate the link. We are never getting to that step, because of the missing mysqli in the line above. I did do a global search to confirm that it never got defined to double check though, and it hasn't been.

Comment: @AndyMercer are you sure there isn't anything pointing to an earlier install? check your `.ini` file's path for it or WP. Maybe the new install uses a new path or vice-versa.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I considered that, but all the earlier installed of PHP were working. It's only when I installed 7.1 that it started breaking. I just ran a global search of the entire WAMP folder for all `php.ini` files. Every single one has `extension=php_mysqli.dll` allowed. I think what is happening with the symlink is that it's pointing to a file in the PHP directory called `phpForApache.ini`. So I checked all those and they are enabled as well.

Comment: @AndyMercer Well Andy, I am baffled. Only thing I can think of to ask is; did you restart after doing the new install? and did you instruct the install to use new or old system files including that paths?

Comment: I've got it! The issue is a very WAMP specific problem. I'm going to write an answer so that if anyone else has the issues they might see this.

Comment: *"I've got it!"* - You mean [*"By George, I've got it!"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDSPwexlyTo) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Background

First off, a bit of into about the way that WAMPServer handles `php.ini` files. If you use `phpinfo()`, you may notice that the path to the loaded `ini` file is **NOT** the `ini` file in the PHP installation. It instead points to the Apache installation.

[image]

But if you look at it, it's a `0KB` symlink. What is actually is is a link to an `ini` file in the PHP installation. But it isn't the `php.ini`, it instead points to `phpForApache.ini`. So this:

```
...\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\php.ini
```

is actually

```
...\wamp64\bin\php\php[VERSION]\phpForApache.ini
```

So, you can ignore what is in the Apache folder and focus on your `ini` files in the PHP folder. However, you can't ignore the `php.ini`. You need to correct both.

*Kudos to [**Jon Stirling**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934966/jon-stirling) to suggesting checking the loaded configuration file in `phpInfo()`.*

## What I Did

I installed PHP 7.1 from the PHP website, and forgot to transfer my `ini` files over from the PHP 7.0 installation. I instead used the default `ini` files provided by the PHP website.

That didn't work, because there are tweaks in the `ini` files that are needed to make PHP work with WAMP. So I copied the two `ini` files over from my 7.0.x folder, and then it started working, mostly, except for the error with mysqli.

## Root Cause of my Problem

After scratching at this for an hour, [**Fred -ii-**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii)'s [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848269/php-7-1-x-mysqli-connect-isnt-defined-extension-is-turned-on?noredirect=1#comment74734806_43848269) finally got me to the answer. I had PHP trying to reference old extension files. Here is why:

The `php.ini` file and the `phpForApache.ini` file, provided by WAMP, both hard code some paths. For example, the extensions folder path for PHP 7.0.10 is coded as this:

```
extension_dir ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/"
```

I had copied the `ini` files over, but they were pointing to the extension folder for 7.0. The `dll` files for 7.0.x don't work with 7.1.x.

## Answer

I went into the two files (`php.ini` `phpForApache.ini`) in the PHP 7.1.4 folder, and globally replaced all instances of the text "7.0.10" to "7.1.4". And now it's all working.

Comment: Cool, I guess it's kind of what I mentioned [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848269/php-7-1-x-mysqli-connect-isnt-defined-extension-is-turned-on?noredirect=1#comment74734806_43848269), *yes?*

Comment: Yes indeed. I've referenced your comment in the answer. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks Andy and you're most welcome. I'm glad to see that this was resolved, *cheers!*

Comment: IF you use the menus provided i.e. `wampmanager->php->php.ini` to edit the CORRECT `php.ini` you will edit the Correct php.ini file

Comment: Correct, though due to the nature of symlinks, the file path shown in the text editor will appear to be the version in the Apache folder, when you are actually editing the version in your current PHP folder.